# Server-side Content Filters / Facets

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to build site that'll have a few hundred posts in a grid. How to implement a filter mechanism (color, size etc) such as `mixitup.kunkalabs.com` but one that fetches data as an `ajax` event rather than loading all posts and then filtering them?

I'm using codeigniter as a php framework

Comment: What have you tried already and what do you know about the system? Now it's like walking into a garage and asking how to replace the gearbox on a car

Comment: hey @mvbrakel, havent gotten around to trying anything yet since this plugin I referenced - MixItUp is better suited for front end use. So if you have 1000 posts and need to filter them, the plugin will likely need those 1000 posts loaded first. Whereas what I'm looking for suggestions on is a similar filtering system but one that fetches data based on user requests from the server.